# Excel VBA Clearing range after copy and pasting range to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a code where the workbook detects if the current month has a sheet assigned to it or not and if not then the workbook will create a new sheet with the current month. After creating a new sheet it would copy and paste a certain range from the main sheet onto the new one. My problem is that after doing so I use a Range.Clear to clean the range that I copy pasted however it seems to be clearing it BEFORE copy-pasting.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    nowMonth = Month(Now)
    nowYear = Year(Now)
    sheetNameStr = nowMonth & "," & nowYear

    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetNameStr = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
        End If
    Next Sheet
    If sheetExists = False Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = sheetNameStr
        MsgBox ("New sheet named " & sheetNameStr & "was created")
    End If
    Sheets("Main").Activate

    Worksheets("Main").Range("A4:D300").Copy Worksheets(sheetNameStr).Range("A1")

    Worksheets("Main").Range("A6:D300").Clear
End Sub
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: Your code works for me.  (a) What sheet is the `Change` event code in?  (I assume it isn't in "Main", or it would crash.)  (b) Do you have any other event-type code?  (c) Do you have more than one workbook open, with a sheet called "Main" in more than one of them?  (If so, perhaps you are copying the data and then clearing it, but just from the wrong workbook.)

Comment: @YowE3K (a) I'm pretty sure it's under main but I don't know how to check. (b) that's the only event type code I have (c) Only one workbook open

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens: the `.Clear` method causes `Worksheet_Change` to fire again; the `Copy` operation is repeated, clearing the destination; then the second `Clear` doesn't change anything, the source having been cleared already, and both `Worksheet_Change` procedures exit.

You have to surround your code with:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Here's the updated code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nowMonth As Integer
    Dim nowYear As Integer
    Dim sheetNameStr As String
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oNewSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sheetExists As Boolean

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    nowMonth = Month(Now)
    nowYear = Year(Now)
    sheetNameStr = nowMonth & "," & nowYear

    sheetExists = False
    For Each oSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sheetNameStr = oSheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit For 'Found, can exit the loop.
        End If
    Next
    If Not sheetExists Then
        Set oNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        oNewSheet.Name = sheetNameStr
        MsgBox "New sheet named " & sheetNameStr & " was created."
    End If

    Me.Activate
    Me.Range("A4:D300").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNameStr).Range("A1")
    Me.Range("A6:D300").Clear

Recover:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oNewSheet = Nothing
    Set oSheet = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Recover
End Sub
```

Notice that `Worksheets` is now qualified by `ThisWorkbook`; otherwise, your code would be referring to whichever workbook is active. Also, `Sheets("Main")` was replaced by `Me` as I assume your code is behind the `Main` worksheet and `Me`, from there, is the worksheet itself. Finally, whenever you turn `EnableEvents` off, you must provide adequate error handling to turn it back on in case of issues.

**Edit**

Here's the original code with just minimal changes to handle EnableEvents:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    nowMonth = Month(Now)
    nowYear = Year(Now)
    sheetNameStr = nowMonth & "," & nowYear

    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetNameStr = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Sheet

    If Not sheetExists Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = sheetNameStr
        MsgBox ("New sheet named " & sheetNameStr & "was created")
    End If
    Sheets("Main").Activate

    Worksheets("Main").Range("A4:D300").Copy Worksheets(sheetNameStr).Range("A1")

    Worksheets("Main").Range("A6:D300").Clear

Recover:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Recover
End Sub
```

Comment: Good catch on the EnableEvents but Worksheet_Change is private in a worksheet's code sheet and some parentage can be assumed to default. I'm m ore concerned that `sheetExists = True` could potentially be overwritten in the loop unless an exit for was introduced after a match was made.

Comment: If the change was initiated from another (active) workbook - probably not the case here - then the non-qualified `Worksheets` would point to the wrong workbook. I personally qualify fanatically. As for overwriting `sheetExists`, it can't happen since Excel enforces distinct tab names. I'll add the `Exit For` nevertheless to show good practice.

Comment: @Excelosaurus I tried your code but now it clears the data from 'main' and instead of copying it onto the new page it only copies one line

Comment: Is the Worksheet_Change code behind the Main worksheet? If not, replace Me by Worksheets("Main"). At any rate, you can take your original code; just sandwich it between Application.EnableEvents =  False and Application.EnableEvents =  True.

Comment: @Excelosaurus Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by behind the main worksheet but I assume it is.